# query builder selecting data codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to ask about selecting data in codeigniter. I did write " With no registration: " in flashdata. What query must I include in this code to show the id from the database so it can be

> "Congratulation! Your data has been registered with No Registration: 1"

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
    Congratulation! Your data has been registered with No Registration:'. $id .' </div>');
redirect('User');
```

[Screenshot of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUHyb.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter has an [insert_id()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/helpers.html) function that returns the id of an item that has just been inserted. However it will only work if you call it immediately after the insert function.

```
// Insert your data into the table
$this->db->insert('users', [
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'age' => 50
]);

// Immediately get the id.
$id = $this->db->insert_id();

// Set your feedback message
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', ' Congratulation! Your data has been registered with No Registration:'. $id .' ');
```

Otherwise if you added your data a couple of queries ago, You may try getting the id of the last inserted item assuming the id is auto increment.

PS. Only use this solution only if you are sure that the item has been added into the database.

```
// Count all rows in the table
$count = $this->db->count_all('users');
// Limit result to 1 row using the count as an offset
$this->db->limit(1, $count-1);
$data = $this->db->get('users')->result();

$id = empty($data) ? null : $data[0]->id;

// Set your feedback message
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', ' Congratulation! Your data has been registered with No Registration:'. $id .' ');
```

If you need more help, please edit your question and submit the code where you are trying to get the id so that i can better help you.